# Double Tap to zoom ScrollView React Native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, zooming

Is there any way to implement zooming in when a user double-taps the screen within a Scrollview?

I know there is pinch to zoom and I was looking for some way to do the same thing with a double tap but none of zoom views I found worked well with a ScrollView.

Anybody know what kind of method I could use to accomplish this>

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something similar to this. I have an image in a ScrollView and I wanted to zoom the image on double press. My setup looks like:

```
<ScrollView
  ref={ref => { this.scrollView = ref; }}
>
  <View {...this.gestureResponder.panHandlers}>
    <Image />
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

In `onPanResponderRelease` in my PanResponder I look for a double press and zoom the ScrollView with my reference to it: `this.scrollView.scrollResponderZoomTo()`

This link helped me to figure out how to detect double press: https://gist.github.com/brunotavares/3c9a373ba5cd1b4ff28b